# Find Binary in a dir of text files Python or Bash

Tags: python, bash, logging, binary

I have a series of log files that are all text.

If a certain error happens it results in binary being inserted in the text.

I want a Python or Bash script that will:

1. Go through the text files (logs) in the dir
2. Show the line that includes the binary
3. Give me the line number where it occurs as well as the file name

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Do you have a specific question about this project? Stack Overflow is not for doing all the work for you.

Comment: Do you know the sequence of bytes you're looking for?

Comment: `grep` is your friend.

Comment: My  specific question was in the original question.

Perhaps I could have reworded it as:
"Can anyone help my with writing a bash or python script that
1. Will go through the text files (logs) in the dir
2. Then Show the line that includes the binary
3. And give me the line number where it occurs as well as the file name

There is no specific binary.  It is always different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what worked for me in Python.

```
import os
import sys

def main():

  if len(sys.argv) < 2:
    print('Usage: python3 hasbinary.py <DIR>')
    return -1

  DIR = sys.argv[1]

  for file in os.listdir(DIR):
    msgs = []
    if file.endswith('.log'):
      print(f'Reading file {file}.')
      with open(DIR + '/' + file, 'rb') as f:
        msgs = msgs + f.readlines()
      for msg in msgs:
        try:
          msg.decode()
        except:
          print(f'Contains binary data: {msg}')

if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```